# Restart geometry optimization in Gaussian after hangup error

Tags: gaussian, geometry-optimization

I am trying to optimize the geometry of a paraquat molecule interacting with a gold bulk. The optimization is stopping after a few steps. The error shown in the `.log` file is "Error: hangup".

Is there a posibility to restart the optimization after the hangup error from the `.chk` file? If so, how does the new `.gjf` file look like?

Thank you for your answers!

Edit: Here is the Error message:

```
Error: hangup
Error: hangup
   rax 0000000000001318, rbx 00002ab521c484e8, rcx 00002ab521c429e8
   rdx 00002ab521c08528, rsp 00007ffedcbb6600, rbp 00007ffedcbb6a30
   rsi 00002ab521c440a8, rdi 00002ab521c09be8, r8  00002ab521c45768
   r9  00002ab521c0b2a8, r10 00002ab521c46e28, r11 00002ab521c0c968
   r12 00002ab521c0e028, r13 00002ab521c49ba8, r14 00002ab521c262e8
   r15 00002ab521c0f6e8
   rax fffffffffffffffc, rbx 00007ffd823b4610, rcx 00002b3e3d62424a
   rdx 0000000000000000, rsp 00007ffd823b45d8, rbp 0000000000000001
   rsi 00007ffd823b4610, rdi 0000000000004d5a, r8  00002b3e3d9063c0
   r9  00007ffd823b4530, r10 0000000000000000, r11 0000000000000246
   r12 00007ffd823b4630, r13 00007ffd823ba000, r14 0000000000000000
   r15 00007ffd823bb000
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x11c00) [0x2ab51f8fbc00]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x102d3ff]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x1029914]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0xe2d93d]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x95b896]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x92f836]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x6db95b]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x4ced25]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x4d5515]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x4bc6fe]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x523c36]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x429326]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x41b189]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x412b1b]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x412a24]
  /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x2ab51fe27a35]
  /opt/g16/l502.exe() [0x40d169]
```

Comment: +1 Could you post the error part of your log file please? it would help in understanding what exactly the error is.